# Error while querying data vertx

Tags: vert.x

```
    public static void findAll(Handler<AsyncResult<ChannelInfo[]>> ar)
{
    //getConnection().query("SELECT &", arg1)
    getConnection().queryWithParams("SELECT * FROM Servers", new JsonObject(), res -> {
        if (res.succeeded() && res.result().size() > 0) {
            ChannelInfo[] channels = new ChannelInfo[res.result().size()];
            int count = 0;

            for (JsonObject row : res.result()) {
                channels[count++] = new ChannelInfo()
                    .setId(row.getInteger("srv_id"))
                    .setName(row.getString("srv_name"))
                    .setIp(row.getString("srv_ip"))
                    .setServerDomain(row.getString("srv_domain"))
                    .setPort(row.getInteger("srv_port"))
                    .setPosition(row.getInteger("srv_position"))
                    .setPromiseToFightFlag(row.getBoolean("srv_promise_to_fight_flag"))
                    .setMoreServerFlag(row.getBoolean("srv_more_server_flag"))
                    .setMaxRoom(row.getInteger("srv_max_room"))
                    .setNumber(row.getInteger("srv_number"))
                    .setAllowedRoomTypeId(row.getInteger("srv_allowed_room_type_id"))
                    .setLimitMinLV(row.getInteger("srv_limit_min_lv"))
                    .setLimitMaxLV(row.getInteger("srv_limit_max_lv"))
                    .setMaxClient(row.getInteger("srv_max_client"));
            }

            ar.handle(Future.succeededFuture(channels));
        } else {
            logger.error("Erro ao obter um usuário pelo nome", res.cause());
            ar.handle(Future.failedFuture(res.cause()));
        }
    });
}
```

error: The method queryWithParams(String, JsonArray, Handler>) in the type SQLConnection is not applicable for the arguments (String, JsonObject, ( res) -> {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace ...

```
getConnection().queryWithParams("SELECT * FROM Servers", new JsonObject(), res ...
```

... with:

```
getConnection().queryWithParams("SELECT * FROM Servers", new JsonArray(), res ...
```

The method `queryWithParams` expects the following arguments:

- the query string
- the query parameters
- a handler for dealing with the response

The second argument must be a `JsonArray` **not** a `JsonObject`. In your case you don't appear to be passing in any parameters so supplying an empty `JsonArray` (e.g. `new JsonArray()`) should suffice.

Comment: for (JsonObject row : res.result()) {
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Comment: I'm guessing your last comment represents an exception you encountered **after** making the change I suggested? It looks to me like the Handler instance you pass into `queryWithParams` is not typed to return an Iterable i.e. `res.result()` does not return an `Iterable`. For any further diagnosis it might be best to update your question and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that this issue can be diagnosed.